# Resize video and canvas to a max size

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have to play a local video file in a CANVAS. The CANVAS is inside a div, which has a max width and height.
If I try to resize the video and the CANVAS to that size, instead of appearing resized, the video is cropped. How can I do the resize?

HTML

```
<div>
<video id="video" controls>
<source id="videoSource" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</div>
```

JS

```
if (videoInfo.height > 480)    
    { 
        var AR = videoInfo.width/videoInfo.height;
        videoInfo.height = 480;
        videoInfo.width = 480*AR; 
    }

if (videoInfo.whidth > 848)  
{ 
    var AR = videoInfo.width/videoInfo.height;
    videoInfo.width = 848; 
    videoInfo.height = 848/AR;
}

video.setAttribute('width', videoInfo.width);
video.setAttribute('height', videoInfo.height + VIDEO_HEIGHT_SHIFT);

displayedCanvas.setAttribute('width', videoInfo.width);
displayedCanvas.setAttribute('height', videoInfo.height);
```

Comment: You have a typo at the > 848 line `whidth` should be `width`. Dunno if that happened when you typed the question or if it is actual code.

Comment: Ups, yeah true, thanks.
Anyway that's not the problem

Comment: There is too little code here unfortunately (what is videoInfo, how do you draw the frame, where is the canvas element, how is canvas set up..). Could you setup a fiddle (or inline demo) showing your scenario? (I know video link can be a little bit tricky, but there are open source videos out there you can use in place of your actual video)

Answer (score 0):

I already solved!
You need to use new video dimensions when drawing it in the canvas, like this:

```
ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, videoInfo.width, videoInfo.height);
```